# C++, оптимизация кода для большого набора данных

Tags: c++, оптимизация

Имеется код функции на C++, задача которой обрезать пробелы в конце строки

```
void TrimRight(char* s)
{
    int j = strlen(s) - 1;
    while(s[j]==' ')
    {
        j--;
    }
    s[j + 1] = '\0';
}
```

Проблема в том, что данное решение не оптимизировано по обращениям к памяти (то есть число обращений слишком много), не позволяет работать с действительно большими строками. Как бы следовало поступить, если есть необходимость обрабатывать очень большие строки с очень большим числом пробелов?

Comment: *"данное решение не оптимизировано"* Почему вы так решили? На мой взгляд выглядит нормально.

Comment: Увы, решил так не я, видимо есть более простой способ c меньшим числом обращений (возможно лишним обращением является работа функции 'strlen')

Comment: Длину строки в любом случае надо где-то брать. Если код, который вызывает эту функцию, знает длину строки, то длину можно передавать параметром, а не вычислять через `strlen`.

Comment: Видимо нужно придумать аналог strlen, оптимизированный под большие строки...

Comment: Лучше покажите программу целиком.

Comment: Как таковой полноценной программы нет, только эта функция и тестовая строка

`int main()
{
 char somestr[] = "abc                       ";  
 TrimRight(somestr); 
 cout << somestr << "!";
 system("pause");
}`

Подобная задача решалась здесь http://www.cyberforum.ru/cpp-beginners/thread1651625.html , но ничего более оптимального я там пока не нашёл

Comment: Все-таки как вы определили, что это решение "недостаточно оптимизированно"? Еще, в условии задачи больше ничего не сказано? (Может в середине строки не бывает пробелов?)

Comment: Решил не я, но человек, выдавший это задание, условия идентичны задаче по ссылке, информации о числе пробелов в тексте строки никакой информации нет, вот и остаётся грешить лишь на `strlen`

Comment: Ну, как версии - хотели получить параллельный алгоритм, или алгоритм, читающий сразу по 4/8 байт, или с использованием какой-нибудь векторизации...

Comment: Раз уж это C++, то может от вас ждали использования `std::string`, а не голых указателей `char*`?

Answer (score 2):

В голову приходит такой вариант:

Убрать `strlen`. Сделать цикл по строке, и запоминать позицию последнего встретившегося не-пробела. Как только попадается `\0`, выходить из цикла и втыкать `\0` сразу после запомненной позиции.

Comment: параллельно с вами я тоже об этом думал, в голову пришла вот такая тема:
`void TrimRight3(char* s)
{
    int i=0;
    int line=0;    
 while (s[i] != '\0')
 {
  if(s[i]!=' ')
  line=i;
  i++;
 }
 s[line+1] = '\0';
}`

Comment: а если пробел есть в начале, в середине, то что?...

Comment: @ARHovsepyan Думаю проблем не будет.

Comment: "     проблем  н е б у д е  т       ?       "  как  такую строку анализировать  циклом от начала строки?.. Конечно лучше конечные пробелы анализировать с конца к началу

Comment: HolyBlackCat дело говорит. Если строка очень длинная и количество пробелов в конце сопостовимо с размером строки, то выгоднее при поиске последнего пробела нужно будет читать память заново. В таком случае можно в цикле в strlen, который сверяет символы с 0, делать ещё одно сравнение с ' ', и запоминать последнюю встречу НЕ пробела. Чтений из памяти будет меньше на примерно количество пробелов в конце, количество сравнений больше на длину строки.

Comment: @ARHovsepyan - _анализировать с конца к началу_ - это возможно только в том случае, если у нас уже есть длина строки. А иначе сперва придётся использовать `strlen`. От чего данный алгоритм как раз избавляет.

Comment: В общем мой второй ответ также не устроил, я хз, как можно сделать число пробегов меньше чем 1, и это было задание на младшего программиста, наверно, хорошо, что не взяли

Comment: @Клаус - хм, этот вариант делает ровно 1 пробег. Меньше может быть только в том случае, если у нас заранее известна длина строки или есть указатель на конец строки. Ну или нужно использовать типы C++.

Comment: я и сам это понимаю, но задание в итоге провалил